# Array.FindIndex Exceptions

Tags: arrays, vb.net, exception

I am calling  Array.FindIndex with a lambda expression as follows to find the index in my "Source" Array... of where the value matches the "LName" property in my LSource Object)

'the code enters here with a NEW LSource to Add OR to increment the count of an existing one:

```
Dim Indx as integer = Array.FindIndex(Source, Function(x As LSource) x.LName.ToLower = curSource)
    If indx = -1 then
If Source Is Nothing Then ReDim Preserve Source(0) Else ReDim Preserve Source(UBound(Source) + 1)
    Dim myNewLSource AS New LSource
     myNewLSource.LName = "John"
     myNewLSource.Whatever = "Whatever"
     myNewLSource.Count = 0
    Source(UBound(Source)) =  myNewLSource
    Else
    Source(indx).Count +=1
    End if
```

I am getting the error object reference is not set to an object (x was nothing).  Tried instanciating it in the lamda but it says its not allowed.

Thank you

Comment: Here: `Dim Source() As LSource` you're just defining the Type. `Source` doesn't contain anything. What is the array that contains the value you want to find? Is `LSource` a Type?

Comment: Source is an array of the type LSource.  LSource is a type...correct.

Comment: Updated to reflect the context of what is going on.

Comment: The code you have now is completely different than what you had before and, sorry to say it, it doesn't make sense. Think about hat you're doing in the that first line. -- The content of `Source` is still undefined.

Comment: Source is already defined to be an Array of LSource.  Some things can be automatically assumed.  So when it runs to this code block.  Source is just empty but already initialized to hold LSource type

Comment: If it's empty, what will you find searching it? Can you search an empty collection? -- Possibly, remove any `ReDim Preserve` from your code and use a `List(Of SomeType)` -- Won't solve the current problem. You should describe what you're actually trying to do. For sure not search an empty collection for a value that cannot be there.

Comment: At the start of every application arent most arrays empty.  This array fills up eventually.  But it can't fill if I can't check if something exists because it errors.

Comment: If an Array/List are empty, then their Length/Count is `0`.

Comment: I understand this..... my question is why is it telling me x is nothing in the lambda expression when I want to check to see if the item exists in my Array.  I am expecting to get a return of -1 so that I can add a new cell to the array and assign it.

Comment: You cannot test the content of Property values of non-existing items. That's all there is  to it. Check the Length/Count before anything else.

Comment: It also errors when there are contents in it....

Comment: Probably another error. The Lambda is `dim idx = Array.FindIndex(Source, Function(x) x.LName.ToLower().Equals(curSource))`, assuming `Source` contains objects with a Property named `LName` of Type `String` which is not null.

Comment: I just went ahead and created my own findindex function to return the -1 value that I need to add the first item to the array.  The Array.FindIndex method is flawed if it is unable to return a -1 value when there is nothing in the array.